# C++ operator delete overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, delete-operator

I am building my application with a third party library which seems to have an overloaded operator delete defined. I was investigating a dump and I noticed that the third party operator delete is being called for stuff that I'm allocating with in my program - instead of libstdc++ operator delete. Is it possible to control which operator delete is called via some linkage option or order?

Thank you for your help.

Edit: I also just remembered: I should probably verify which new operator I end up using as that would probably explain why my application is crashing.

Comment: Why do you need this? Presumably if a custom delete operator was defined, that's because the class has custom allocation requirements and probably also has a custom new operator.

Comment: Don't expect anything to work should you decide to tinker with their custom deallocation routine.

Comment: I don't want to tinker with their deallocation routine. I just don't want stuff that I'm allocating in my program to use their operator. Does that make sense? I realize the question is not clear. I'll clarify it now.

Comment: Have you learned about the placement `new` operator?  Once you have learned, it will grow apparent to you why overloaded `delete` is odd.  I do not know your library, but there is more than a small chance that your library vendor does not quite understand placement `new` -- in which case you may be in trouble.  Good luck.

Comment: Yep. I am aware of placement new and delete. I do think I'm in trouble which is why I'm hoping to find a way around this. Thanks for your help anyway. I emailed them already... let's see what I hear back.